# Flex - XML generated with Javascript to an ArrayCollection

Tags: javascript, xml, apache-flex

Is it possible to convert an XML string generated by a javascript return, into an ArrayCollection? I have looked into SimpleXMLEncoder as a possible solution, but that seems to deal more with a file than a string. My XML tree is pretty detailed so I need something to handle multilayer XML nodes.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could convert XML to an ArrayCollection, but you'd have to write your own code to do that conversion.  I believe it is something too specific to your XML data set to be easily created generically.

However, I'd recommend you consider using an [XMLListCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html) instead.  That is usually what is used when you have XML as the source.

Comment: Thanks man that's what I'm working on at the moment. I'll post any success/failures that are coming